# how to change the font color (style) of columns/rows in a sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer

I have created a list in my SP 2010 site via the Create List using Import Spreadsheet option. Unfortunately, for whatever reason (despite the fact that I have formatted my excel document all the same), some columns end up with some markup/formatting that carries over to the SP list and some dont.

Secondly whenever I create a new row in the list, all text is formatted with a grey color by default. I want all the text to be black. Short of manually making each field a rich text field and changing the text to black, is there any way to make all the text in all the columns of all the rows black? I would hope that SP would provide SOME styling options like this by default but I dont see any such option. Does that mean you MUST alter the sites css in SPD? If so where do i find the property/file that controls the list?

Answer (score 1):

List -> List Settings -> Come to bottom You'll find View, There is default view "All Items", click.

Then you 'll find style at that page, SP presents you some style options. Maybe they are useful to you. I'll check how to edit style .

Answer (score 0):

To change the font color on the datasheet view

site actions -> site setting -> Look and Feel -> Site Theme

Scroll down to the Text Background.  Change "Dark 2" to #000000 which is black

This will make the font in the datasheet black.

This link has a decent explanation of what the some of the other settings do.  Scroll to this section: "Where the Theme Colors Appear in SharePoint"

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/1/9/using-powerpoint-2010-to-create-a-custom-theme-for-sharepoin.html

Comment: The "Site Actions" options will change everything on that site, not just your list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason some fields are formatted and others are not is because I suspect some of your columns are multi-line text columns with Rich Text (or Enhanced Rich Text), which inherit the formatting of the data you imported, while your other columns are plain text (and use the SP2010 default font).  Make your MLT fields plain text and all will have the same fonts (or apply the default font to the data you are importing before importing it).

Answer (score -1):

Check [this link](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2012_06_01_archive.html) may it helps..